# How to update the state of child component from parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just getting started with React and not able to figure this out.

```
    <Select>
      <Search term={this.state.filename} />
    </Select>
```

Select component is for selecting a file, I want to set the initial value of input text inside the Search component to be the filename.

Here is the Search component

```
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="search"
      value={this.props.term}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  </form>
```

Now, whenever user tries to change the value of input from the initial value set by the parent, I set the state of the child with the new input value but this triggers re-render of the child which resets the input value. What is the correct way around this?

What I am currently thinking is if I assign the value of input like this `value={this.props.term}`
, then changing the state will trigger re-render of the child with the filename as the default value and user will be able to edit it.

Comment: Can you put the handleChange function?

Answer (score 1):

Try have onChange on Search be delegated to a props so that your parent will be the one that sets the value when onChange is called on child.

```
onChange={this.props.onInputChange}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `value={this.props.term}`, which makes the input a controlled component. The value here will always be same as `this.props.term`, which is the state from parent component. `<Search term={this.state.filename} />`

I guess what you really want to do here is change parent's state inside child component.

Then you should pass a function from parent component to child component. The function will change the state of parent component. You should define Something in parent component like these:

```
onChildInputChange(term) {
    this.setState({term: term })
}
```

Then pass it to child component through props

```
<Select>
   <Search term={this.state.filename} onChildInputChange={this.onChildInputChange} />
</Select>
```

so that in child component you can do this:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="search"
      value={this.props.term}
      onChange={()=>{this.props.onChildInputChange()}}
    />
  </form>
```