# ReactJS, How to update the State of the PARENT from the CHILD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

If I have a parent that sets a state and passes it to a child, how can I change the state of the parent FROM the child?

```
    // parent
    this.state = {
        status: 'doing...'
    }

    // child render
    <div>{this.props.state.status}</div>
    // child function triggered by an onClick
    update = () => this.setState(status: 'finished');
```

Something like this doesn't work

```
    // parent
    this.state = {
        status: this.props.state.status
    }

    // or child
    this.props.setState(status: 'finished');

    // or child
    getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
       console.log('I'm never executed)
       this.setState({ status: nextProps.state.status});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As said here

[How to update the state of child component from parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676134/how-to-update-the-state-of-child-component-from-parent)

and going with option 2, what I didn't understand is how to pass a function through props.

If in the child I define there `<CHILD message={this.message}` then I can call that function with `this.props.message` in CHILD.

Comment: Yea better to delete this question then... `:)`

Comment: Yes? I never know what to do in these cases, it could be useful for future readers (I have answered as I was answering the question but now I cannot mark it until 2 days from now)

Comment: That works... Alright... Great mate! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

We had stumbled upon the same issue. The way we did was, outsource the original state changer to the parent itself. Don't manage states between parent component and child one. If you need to do it, dispatch it using Redux.

For now, the best thing I could say you is:

```
// Parent Component
class Parent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      SomeVar: "Something"
    });
  }
  render() {
    <Child onUpdate={this.handleClick} />
  }
}
```

And now with the child, it's easier to send the values this way.

Comment: Thanks! I've just posted what has worked for me, what at the end was quite simple. In any case, I still haven't jumped into Redux :_)

Comment: @Gerard Ha ha... Good for you... We tried implementing that and stuck infinitely into Redux... LoL.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Thank you! `:)`